# How to sort by key and then by nested value

Tags: python, dictionary

consider the following structure

```
 'source-document01013.txt': {'AAAGCTTACA': {'endPos': '141',
                                             'startPos': '132'},
                              'AAATCTTAGA': {'endPos': '105',
                                             'startPos': '96'},
                              'AAATGTCCCC': {'endPos': '75',
                                             'startPos': '66'}
                             }
```

i would like to sorted it by the `'source-document01013.txt'` and then by the startPos, how can i go about that?

i had the line below previously but now i added a nested dict and this broke.

`newDict = sorted(dictionary.items(), key = lambda x: (x[1], int(x[1]['startPos'])))`

error: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: Post the error you get that someone can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = []
for k, v in sorted(dictionary.items()):
    l.append((k, sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[1]['startPos']))))
```